# Where is the default save spreadsheet path stored at?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have searched for about 3 or 4 days to find the storage location for the phpspreadsheet save file path. The stock answer here and anywhere else is to insert the path I want in `$writer->save($filename)`, before `$filename`. I have tried, and it does not work.

I will show in code and printout. This is on a local computer, Win 10 pro. Current version of xampp. All work in localhosst environment, never to go outside the firewall.

The code from the phpspreadsheet sample **33_Chart_create_line.php**. As I said, tried inserting my desired path. So, where is the default path stored?

```
//Code     // Save Excel 2007 file
$filename = $helper->getFilename(__FILE__);
echo "file name the variable : " . $filename . "<br>";
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$callStartTime = microtime(true);
$writer->save($filename);
$helper->logWrite($writer, $filename, $callStartTime);

//And my try:
// Save Excel 2007 file
$filename = $helper->getFilename(__FILE__);
echo "file name the variable : " . $filename . "<br>";
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$callStartTime = microtime(true);
$writer->save("C:/xampp/htdocs/tmp/" . $filename);
$helper->logWrite($writer, $filename, $callStartTime);
```

Normal printout message:

> 18:45:18 Write Xlsx format to
>   C:\Users\HAL1GB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/phpspreadsheet/33_Chart_create_line.xlsx
>   in 0.0233 seconds

Message when when I insert my path:

> 18:45:18 Write Xlsx format to
>   C:\Users\HAL1GB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/phpspreadsheet/33_Chart_create_line.xlsx
>   in 0.0233 seconds

As you see, it just prepends my path to the default path and then can't do the save. Echo of $filename, shows the path comes from the `$helper->getFilename(FILE);` call. File name the variable: `C:\Users\HAL1GB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/phpspreadsheet/33_Chart_create_line.xlsx`

Error Message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could
>   not open
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/tmp/C:\Users\HAL1GB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/phpspreadsheet/33_Chart_create_line.xlsx
>   for writing. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MySql\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php:218
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MySql\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\samples\Chart\33_Chart_create_line.php(105):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx->save('C:/xampp/htdocs...') #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MySql\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php
>   on line 218

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save the file don't use the `$filename` in the actual name. Specify the complete path and name of where you want to save the file and where. Using your example that would be:

```
$writer->save('C:/xampp/htdocs/tmp/Example_File.xlsx');
```

The `file` class that comes with PHPSpreadSheet includes a function named `sysGetTempDir`. In that function it will use the system defined temporary file path, which is what you're seeing, OR, if it is defined and writeable, the value of the `upload_tmp_dir` setting in the PHP INIfile.

If you want to control where the files are created set the `upload_tmp_dir` value in your PHP INI file to the path desired.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I also came up with a fix. $filename = basename($helper->getFilename(__FILE__));
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$callStartTime = microtime(true);
$writer->save($saveDir . $filename);
use basename returns only the file name. I can the also use my own path.

Comment: Although I gave Dave the check mark. I sure would like to have someone provide the answer to the basic question, where can I change the default save to location?

Comment: I updated my answer with the details on how PHPSpreadSheet decides where to write files and how you may change it. I would certainly recommend being specific on where you want something to be stored and named rather than relying on an obscure set of settings that you may not remember the next time you visit your code or that the next person who looks at your code tries to figure out.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the edit. That is what I was looking for. I looked in my php.ini file. It is not coming from there. I'm going to try to find sysGetTempDir.

Comment: It calls the PHP function to get the system temp directory. If you want to control it set the value in the ini file.